# Displaying MySQL output in PHP as rows rather than columns

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pivot, transpose

Good afternoon all :)

I would like to display my MySQL output on a PHP page as rows rather than columns for easier mobile viewing and scrolling (so the user can just scroll down the data instead of across).

I'd read about pivots and transposing but wasn't sure what was the most appropriate way to transform the return data output on the webpage. Please can you advise on what is best to use? It looks like it's easier to do it in PHP rather than MySQL?

I'm using a standard post form, connection PDO, isset, thead, php echo td and th etc.

My current code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

    <title></title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
  </head>

<body>

<h1>Find people</h1>

    <form method="post">
        <label for="people">Enter person</label>
        <input type="text" id="people" name="people">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="View Results">

    </form>

<?php

//error_reporting(-1);
//ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  try {
    require "./config.php";
    require "./common.php";

    $connection = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);

    $sql = "SELECT *
    FROM Basics
    WHERE UniqueID = :people";

    $people = $_POST['people'];

    $statement = $connection->prepare($sql);
    $statement->bindParam(':people', $people, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $statement->execute();

    $result = $statement->fetchAll();
  } catch(PDOException $error) {
    echo $sql . "<br>" . $error->getMessage();
  }
}
?>


<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  if ($result && $statement->rowCount() > 0) { ?>
    <h2>Results</h2>

    <table>
<?php echo '<table border="1">';?>
      <thead>
<tr>
  <th>Field 1</th>
  <th>Field 2</th>
  <th>Field 3</th>
</tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
  <?php foreach ($result as $row) { ?>
      <tr>
<td><?php echo escape($row["Field 1"]); ?></td>
<td><?php echo escape($row["Field 2"]); ?></td>
<td><?php echo escape($row["Field 3"]); ?></td>


      </tr>
    <?php } ?>
      </tbody>
  </table>
  <?php } else { ?>
     <br>No results found for <?php echo escape($_POST['people']); ?>, as the data has likely not been added yet.
  <?php }
} ?>

<!--
<?php if (isset($_POST['submit']) && $statement) { ?>
  <?php echo escape($_POST['people']); ?> successfully found.
<?php } ?>
-->

  </body>
</html>
```

My current output:

[image]

Current example output:

[image]

Output example I would like:

[image]

Similar to this example I found (can be in a table or not like below):

[image]

**Update edit:**

Looks like I just needed to use ul and li!

```
<ul>
<li><b>Name:</b> <?php echo escape($row["Name"]); ?></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Have you tried swapping your <tr> and <th>'s?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I just needed to use ul and li!

```
<ul>
<li><b>Name:</b> <?php echo escape($row["Name"]); ?></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use array_walk() to loop over the rows and within that loop, start the tr-tag, loop over the values of the current row, output them as td-elements, exit the td-loop, output the closing tr-tag and exit the tr-loop. Not that fancy solution but simple.